# How to sum columns in python based on column with not empty string

Tags: python-3.x

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'key1':[np.nan,'a','b','b','a'],
'data1':[2,5,8,5,7],
'key2':['ab', 'aa', np.nan, np.nan, 'one'],
'data2':[1,5,9,6,3],
'Sum over columns':[1,10,8,5,10]})
```

Hi everybody, could you please help me with following issue:
I'm trying to sum over columns to get a sum of data1 and data2.

If column with string (key1) is not NaN and if column with string (key2) is not NaN then sum data1 and data2. The result I want is shown in the sum column. Thank your for your help!

Comment: Do you have a NaN or the *string* `'NaN'`?  (Your original post made it seem like the former, but your new code is clearly the latter.)

Comment: Hi, I meant NaN not 'NaN'

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.apply` method of `df` on `axis=1` and `numpy`'s *array multiplication* function to get your desired output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
'key1':[np.nan,'a','b','b','a'],
'data1':[2,5,8,5,7],
'key2':['ab', 'aa', np.nan, np.nan, 'one'],
'data2':[1,5,9,6,3]})

df['Sum over columns'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.multiply(x[0:2], ~x[2:4].isnull()).sum(), axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df['Sum over columns'] = np.multiply(df[['data1','data2']], ~df[['key1','key2']].isnull()).sum(axis=1)
```

Either one of them should yield:

```
#    data1  data2 key1 key2  Sum over columns
# 0      2      1  NaN   ab                 1
# 1      5      5    a   aa                10
# 2      8      9    b  NaN                 8
# 3      5      6    b  NaN                 5
# 4      7      3    a  one                10
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @mile.d, if this worked for you, please consider marking it answered with the check mark next to the answer.